# Groovy regex with hyphen isn't matching

Tags: regex, string, groovy

I want to write a regex that will match any time the substring "my-app" is encountered inside any given string.

I have the following Groovy code:

```
String regex = ".*my-app*"
String str = getStringFromUserInput()
if(str.matches(regex) {
    println "Match!"
} else {
    println "Doesn't match..."
}
```

When `getStringFromUserInput()` returns a string like "*blahmy-appfizz*", the code above still reports `Doesn't match...`. So I figured that hyphens must be a special character in regexes and tried changing the regex to:

```
String regex = ".*my--app*"
```

But still nothing has changed. Any ideas as to where I'm going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The hyphen is no special character.

`matches` validates the entire input. Try:

```
String regex = ".*my-app.*"
```

Note that `p*` matches zero or more `p`'s and `p.*` matches a `p` followed by zero or more chars (other than line breaks).

Assuming `getStringFromUserInput()` does not leave any line break char in the input. In which case you'd need to do a `trim()` to get rid of it, since the `.*` does not match line break chars.

Answer (score 1):

`String.contains` seems like a simpler solution than a regex, e.g.

```
String stringFromUser = 'my-app'
assert 'foomy-appfoo'.contains(stringFromUser)
assert !'foo'.contains(stringFromUser)
```